# Strings in a dictionary. A partial order, strict order, and total order?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Question: 
The domain is the set of all words in the English language (as defined by, say, Webster's dictionary). Word $x$ is related to word $y$ if $x$ appears as a substring of y. For example, "ion" is related to the word "companions" because the letters i-o-n appear in order in the word "companions".
Is it a partial order, strict order, and is it a total order?

My thoughts:
It is reflexive because a $x$ being a substring of $y$ makes it a substring of itself. It is transitive because if it is a substring of $y$ and $y$ is a substring of $z$ then it is a substring of $z$. It is antisymmetric because if $x$ is a substring of $y$ and $y$ is a substring of $x$ then they are the same.

Am I doing this right?

Comment: Hint: What is the relation between the words "cat" and "dog"?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you're doing it right, however you have to use the fact that words are finite in order to prove that this is antisymmetric. Consider the infinite case, the word $abababab\ldots$ then it is a substring of the word $babababa\ldots$ and vice versa, but they are not equal.

So it is a partial order. The other two do not hold, but I'll leave it to you to figure out why.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Because the words in the dictionary are finite we can say that it is anti-symmetric. Is it not comparable because there exists elements of the set that are not related?

Comment: That's roughly the idea, albeit your explanation is not well-formulated. Simply observe that if $x$ is a substring of $y$ then the length of $x$ is at most the length of $y$, and vice versa. So if $x\preceq y$ and $y\preceq x$ their length is the same. How many substrings of $y$ have the same length as $y$?

Comment: (Or in other words, if $x\neq y$ and $x$ is a substring of $y$, then it has to be shorter, in which case $y$ cannot possibly be a substring of $x$ as well.)